# How to cut out and save a rectangle from an image?

Tags: java, image-processing

How can cut the image and save it block to another image?

Comment: You should really add some more details to your question or it's likely to be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: What do you have until now? Image formats? Block sizes? Other constraints? Otherwise see the Java tutorials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `src` is a `BufferedImage`, then you can cut the rectangle `(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)` from it and write that to `dst.png` like this:

```
final BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);    

Graphics2D g = dst.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(src, x1, y1, x2, y2, null);
g.dispose();

ImageIO.write(dst, "PNG", new FileOutputStream("dst.png"));
```

Comment: I really need this now for converting Minecraft texture packs, I'm glad you answered such an unclear question.