# java(image processing)

Tags: java

How can cut the image and save it block to another image? image size=150 ,file type=png,number of block=9 ,block size=(x=50,y=50)

Comment: You really aren't giving more details than you did in your first question, which you should have edited instead of posting a new one.  There is an upvoted answer in that one which you should reply to.  How does it not meet your needs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java(image processing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936373/javaimage-processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What is the best java image processing library/approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603283/what-is-the-best-java-image-processing-library-approach)

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Updated, I referenced a previous question.